# Get Objects While Deleting term

Tags: plugin-development, terms

I created a custom taxonomy **organization** for users and I could get specific organization user list by using **get_objects_in_term($term_id, $taxnomy_name)** functions. But, I can't use **get_objects_in_term($term_id, $taxnomy_name)** while deleting term with these below action

```
do_action( 'delete_term_taxonomy', $tt_id );
do_action( 'deleted_term_taxonomy', $tt_id );
do_action( 'delete_term', $term, $tt_id, $taxonomy, $deleted_term );
do_action( "delete_$taxonomy", $term, $tt_id, $deleted_term );
```

My question "Is there any ways to get user list from specific organization before deleting that organization?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`pre_delete_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_delete_term/) hook, which fires before the actual deleting occurs, so the relationships will still be present.

```
function wpse_296972_pre_delete_term( $term_id, $taxonomy_name ) {
    if ( $taxonomy_name === 'organization' ) {
        $objects = get_objects_in_term( $term_id, $taxonomy );

        // Do something with $objects.
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_delete_term', 'wpse_296972_pre_delete_term' );
```

Comment: I didn't know that action exist. I sent 4 hours for that. Big Thanks, Man